# Find places based on place radius, not user radius in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, gps, geolocation, geojson

I need to find places the same way of the follow image.

My collection is:

```
{
    name: "Mc Donalds",
    location: { 
        "type": "Circle",
        "coordinates": [100,0],
        "radius": 20
    }
}
```

With no success, I tried to search using the follow code:

```
db.places.find({
    location: {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [ 110, 10]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

How to get all circles that a Point is contained in, like in the picture?

[image: User point search all places with determinate radius]

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all restaurants near the Point 110,10 - so the once in circle < 200m, than 200 to <500m? So you might want to use geoNear?

```
db.runCommand({ 
"geoNear" : "places", 
"near" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : [110, 10] },
"spherical" : true, 
"distanceMultiplier" : 0.001,
query: { "category": "restaurants" }
})
```

geoNear sorts documents by distance. You can use minDistance / maxDistance parameter or group the result-set accordingly.